# Pinterest Style Image Load

Tags: jquery, css

Just wondering if anyone had knowledge of what Pinterest was doing to make its images fade in like they do.

I'm trying to do something similar on my website but jQuery the bits of code I found here on Stackoverflow do not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".banner").bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeIn(); });
</script>

          <img class="banner" src="/<?php echo $bannerurl ?>" />
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $(".banner").hide();
  $(".banner").bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeIn(); });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You want it to fade in after the page is loaded ?

Comment: or as it's loading. But it usually loads before the rest of the page. Here's the page I'm working with http://broadcasted.tv/show/56/southland/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you may be overcomplicating things.

html:

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="fadein" />
```

CSS:

```
.fadein { display: none; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.fadein').fadeIn(2500);
```

<kbd>[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/4dz5a/)</kbd>

Comment: that's not working on my website, I don't get it.
On .banner http://broadcasted.tv/show/56/southland/

Comment: I added this $('.banner').fadeIn(2500); to my js and this .banner {
 padding-bottom:10px;
 width: 621px;
height: 348px;
display: none;

}

Comment: You've got to put the jquery inside the document.ready function rather than just randomly at the end of a javascript file.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't really be able to work in the morning (cause I do this type of things). Works nicely now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. It's far more efficient to hide via CSS, then fade in via jQuery. If you hide via jQuery, the image shows until the DOM is loaded.